# php: Adding one array as a new level in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assuming I have two arrays:

```
$a = ['a', 'b' => array('Jack', 'John'), 'c'];
$b = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

How can I push `$b` to be "under" the value 'Jack' in `$a`, to make it a multidimensional array? So, the end result should look like this:

```
$ab = ['a', 'b' => ['Jack' => ['1', '2', '3'], 'John'], 'c'];
```

I understand that this changes the value of `$a[1]['Jack'] = 'b'` to become a key, but that's fine with me.

How can I do this?

Comment: `unset($a[1]); $a['b'] = $b;`

Comment: There is no way to *"change the value of $a[1]='b' to become a key,"* but you can remove (one way or another) the value `'b'` from the array and associate a new value to a new key named `'b'`. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and don't stop until you reach the sections ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) and ["Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: How many levels deep could your array be? Just the two, or potentially more? Do you always know the path to `'Jack'`, or do we need to find out what index it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively iterate through the array with a function until you get the right value (`'Jack'`) like this:

```
function iterateArr (&$array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => &$val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                iterateArr($val);
            } elseif ($val == 'Jack') {
                global $b;
                unset($array[$key]);
                $array[$val] = $b;
            }
        }
    }
}

iterateArr($a);
```

For your example, this'd output:

```
['a', 'b' => ['John', 'Jack' => ['1', '2', '3']], 'c']
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/984232)

But the beauty of this is that it'll work no matter how many levels deep your array is, since it's a recursive iterator. e.g., for an array like:

```
['a', 'b' => ['1', '2', '3' => ['i' => ['Jack', 'John'], 'ii', 'ii', 'iv', 'v']], 'c']
```

The output'd be:

```
['a', 'b' => ['1', '2', '3' => ['i' => ['John', 'Jack' => ['1', '2', '3']], 'ii', 'ii', 'iv', 'v']], 'c']
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/984238)

Comment: In production code I would check the value returned by `array_search()` to not unset the wrong value when the searched one does not exist in `$a`. https://3v4l.org/kZKAT

Comment: I just edited my question to better reflect my actual data. The value I'm trying to push an array into is in fact not in the top level of a multi-dimensional array. Your current answer works perfect for values in the top level. Can you help with the new situation?

Comment: @thom_stackoverflow See my updated answer, it works for as many levels deep as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ['a', 'b' => array('Jack', 'John'), 'c'];
$b = ['1', '2', '3'];

unset($a['b'][0]); // go inside array $a and get the first value (B in 
                   // this case) 
                   // Then get the key you wanna change.
                   // Remove that value so we can 'reset' it.
$a['b'][0] = $b;   // set array $b as that value;
```

Comment: @axiac edited answer. Saw it just too late. Also now is the order alright

Comment: The order is still `a, c, array`. But thats not a real problem.

Comment: It's a coincidence. Use `krsort()` and you won't get them in the reverse order. This is because [`0 == 'b'`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and this allows `0` and `'b'` to land in any relative order in the sorted array.

Comment: I just edited my question to better reflect my actual data. The value I'm trying to push an array into is in fact not in the top level of a multi-dimensional array. Your current answer works perfect for values in the top level. Can you help with the new situation?

Comment: @thom_stackoverflow edited answer. practically the same